# Update Table from another Table in SQL Server 2016, plus "could not be bound" issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I came up with my query below but my results don't seam to update anything.

My column `Speedlink_ID` in table `Sheet1` has the same number of cells as `copy_Master_IP_Data` column `Con_SP_ID`.

`Speedlink_ID` has my updated data.

Also, I can't seam to get rid of this

> The multi-part identifier "..." could not be bound.

Its on all of my 2nd table* `Sheet1`

```
UPDATE copy_Master_IP_Data
SET [copy_Master_IP_Data].[CON_SP_ID] = [MSP_DATA_TEST].[dbo].[Sheet1].[Speedlink_ID]
FROM [MSP_DATA_TEST].[dbo].[Sheet1]
WHERE [MSP_DATA_TEST].[dbo].[Sheet1].[Speedlink_ID] = [copy_Master_IP_Data].[CON_SP_ID]

SELECT TOP (1000) [CON_SP_ID]
FROM [copy_Master_IP_Data]
```

Comment: You set the condition:`WHERE [MSP_DATA_TEST].[dbo].[Sheet1].[Speedlink_ID] = [copy_Master_IP_Data].[CON_SP_ID]` so the 2 columns are equal and then you want to update the 2nd column with the value of the 1st column? It does not make sense.

Comment: You say it "doesn't seem to update anything" but you also say that there is a syntax error. It can't be both - a query will not execute if it cannot be compiled. So - which is it? Does nothing or won't compile?

Comment: When the query is ran, the results are the same as what is already in the column = CON_SP_ID.
It dose not update it with the new data from - Speedlink_ID

It runs with the syntax error.

Comment: What new data? You set a condition that the 2 columns are equal. How do you expect them to be different after the update?

Answer (score 1):

Try aliasing the table you're updating it and including it with a join on your other table:

```sql
UPDATE t -- <-- alias of table you are updating
SET    CON_SP_ID = s.Speedlink_ID
FROM   copy_Master_IP_Data t
       join MSP_DATA_TEST.dbo.Sheet1 s on s.Speedlink_ID = t.CON_SP_ID


SELECT TOP (1000) [CON_SP_ID]
FROM [copy_Master_IP_Data]
```

Comment: CON_SP_ID is already equal to Speedlink_ID by the condition: `on s.Speedlink_ID = t.CON_SP_ID`. Can you explain what will be updated by your code?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat . . . Although I prefer your format, the OP's method also works in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I am trying to get it to work atm moment. However, it just shows the same data? The updated data is sitting in a temp table called " sheet1" the column "Speedlink" has the data I need. 

Do I need to swap around the Statement ?

Comment: change update t to update s, and change the SET statement to target the field you want to change

Comment: @Excelnoobster, Thanks. I tried about 3 different ways biased on what you said. No luck so far